# Search for the shortest way to turn a string to another string one character at a time in a given list

Tags: python, list, recursion, search, divide-and-conquer

Given a `list` of strings with the **SAME** length, search for a way to transform a `start` string to an `end` string one character at a time such that every transformed string is still present in the `list` of strings.

**INPUTS!**
Input starts with `T` for the number of test cases. Then, in another line comes `m` asking for the number of strings to put in the list. `m` lines follow asking for the strings of the same length, and then, the last line consists `start` and `end` separated by a space.

Example:

```
List: ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coaster", "coasted"] 
start: roaster
end: booster

Number of String Transformation: 3 (roaster -> rooster -> booster)


List: ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coaster", "coasted"] 
start: booster
end: coasted

Number of String Transformation: 3 (booster -> rooster -> roaster -> coaster -> coasted)


List: ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coaster", "coasted", "coastal"] 
start: roaster
end: coastal

Number of String Transformation: impossible (roaster -> coaster -> coasted -> x -> coastal)
```

Output `impossible` if there is no possible way. Otherwise, output the **shortest** way to transform.

I made a recursive approach but this cannot find every possible solution since it only tries to change indices that are not equal with the `end` string which skips some strings that are present in the `list` that could lead to a possible solution.

My code works for the first example but misses the second one because it does not try out `(booster -> rooster -> etc...)` since it only sees `(booster -> cooster -> coaster -> coasted)` as a possible solution. I'm kinda stuck and I don't know how to resolve this. Can someone show me a better approach?

```
def transformable(word_1, word_2):
    return len([i for i in range(len(word_1)) if word_1[i] != word_2[i]]) == 1

def shortest_transformation(start, end, words):
    queue = [[start]]
    available = set(words).difference({start})
    while queue:
        path = queue.pop()
        if transformable(path[-1], end):
            return path + [end]
        transformables = set(word for word in available if transformable(path[-1], word))
        queue = [path + [word] for word in transformables] + queue
        available = available.difference(transformables)
    return None

T = int(input())

for case in range(T):
    m = int(input())
    words = []
    for inputs in range(m):
        words.append(input())
    
    start, end = input().split()
    
    result = shortest_transformation(start, end, words)
    print(len(result)) if result else print("none")

4
5
booster
rooster
roaster
coaster
coastal
booster coastal
6
booster
rooster
roaster
coaster
coasted
coastal
booster coastal
5
booster
rooster
roaster
coaster
coasted
booster coasted
5
booster
rooster
roaster
coaster
coasted
roaster booster

Output:
none
none
5
3
```

Comment: 1) Have you heard of the shortest path problem? 2) Can you find a relation between the shortest path problem and your problem? 3) Do you know of an algorithm to solve the shortest path problem? 4) Can you inspire yourself from this algorithm to write an algorithm to solve your problem?

Comment: Which one exactly? In our class, we're still talking about divide and conquer algorithms, is that what you're talking about?

Comment: No, I am talking about the shortest path problem: finding the shortest path between two vertices in a graph.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what `T` exactly does, but shouldn't you indent the `result …` and `print(…` lines into the loop over `case`?

Comment: `T` is the number of test cases, meaning there could be multiple cases. I basically just made a loop for the whole process. Also you're right, `result` and `print` was supposed to be inside the loop. I changed it and it still gives error for hidden case 2 and 3.

Comment: Hm, my interpretation would be more like: Read `T`, read `m`, read the `m` words, and then start to loop `for case in range(T):` and do the transformation stuff? Otherwise it seems rather pointless. But I have no experience in how this is usually set up.

Comment: I added a case where there are multiple test cases. Please check my post.

Comment: @muw I see. I'm pretty much out of ideas. The algorithm works fine with all the cases I've tried so far. And I don't see a flaw in it. The only thing which you could try is to add `if len(word_1) != len(word_2): return False` right a the beginning of the definition of `transformable`, to make sure that words of different length don't lead to an `IndexError` ... :(

Comment: It's okay, I really think your code should work. The only problem is how our compiler deals with the inputs. Anyway, I really appreciate your help. Thank you for trying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a suggestion in case you haven't found a solution:

```py
from collections import deque

def transformable(word_1, word_2):
    return len([i for i in range(len(word_1)) if word_1[i] != word_2[i]]) == 1

def shortest_transformation(start, end, words):
    queue = deque([[start]])
    words = set(words).difference({start})
    while queue:
        path = queue.pop()
        if transformable(path[-1], end):
            return path + [end]
        transformables = set(word for word in words if transformable(path[-1], word))
        queue.extendleft(path + [word] for word in transformables)
        words = words.difference(transformables)
    return []
```

This is kind of a breadth first search (via a LILO/FIFO queue by using the `.extendleft()` method of [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque)), which is a good way to search for shortest routes.

For your examples

```py
words = ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coaster", "coasted"] 
start = 'roaster'
end = 'booster'
print(shortest_transformation(start, end, words))

words = ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coaster", "coasted"] 
start = 'booster'
end = 'coasted'
print(shortest_transformation(start, end, words))

words = ["booster", "rooster", "roaster", "coaster", "coasted", "coastal"] 
start = 'roaster'
end = 'coastal'
print(shortest_transformation(start, end, words))
```

the output is

```
['roaster', 'rooster', 'booster']
['booster', 'rooster', 'roaster', 'coaster', 'coasted']
[]
```

If you don't want to use `deque` then this should be equivalent:

```
def shortest_transformation(start, end, words):
    queue = [[start]]
    available = set(words).difference({start})
    while queue:
        path = queue.pop()
        if transformable(path[-1], end):
            return path + [end]
        transformables = set(word for word in available if transformable(path[-1], word))
        queue = [path + [word] for word in transformables] + queue
        available = available.difference(transformables)
    return None
```

Comment: I tried this code but I am facing errors.

Comment: @muw Could you elaborate a bit: What kind of error?

Comment: Well It works with the expected output if I just run it, but when I tried debugging line by line to understand your approach, it gives me these errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:\Program Files\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\workbench.py", line 1598, in event_generate
    handler(event)
  File "I:\Program Files\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\plugins\debugger.py", line 1186, in _handle_debugger_progress
    _current_debugger.handle_debugger_progress(msg)

It's a lot longer than that, there's a lot of errors and I cannot Identify the cause.

Comment: @muw Works well here in debugging mode (PyCharm, on macOS and Windows10)? I think that's a limitation of your environment, which I'm not familiar with -- not a coding error. I have added a version that doesn't use `dequeue`, only a list. Maybe it helps.

Comment: Tried your code once again, it works for the test cases I created, but for our class compiler, it has three hidden test cases, it only passed one while it gave an `IndexError` for the 2 other hidden cases. It's been a day already and I still cannot figure a loophole in your code. Does your code consider multiple paths and only output the shortest way?

Comment: @muw As far as I can see there are only 3 places where an index error could occur: (1) In the function `transformable`, when the 2 given words have different lengths - but that shouldn't happen if I understood the assumptions correctly? (2) In `shortest_transformation`: (a) `path[-1]` if `path == []` - but this can't happen since it starts with a 1-element list which can only become larger. (b) `queue.pop()` if `queue == []` - but this can't happen due to the leading `while queue` … ? Are you sure the input-preprocessing is correct?

Comment: You are correct for the first and second possible cause. I cannot really say more about the third case. I have no detail for the input-preprocessing. All I know is that input first starts with m asking for the number of strings and then m lines follow. Then, one line consisting of two strings (start and end).

Comment: @muw How should the output look like, exactly? E.g. have you replaced `return []` with `return 'impossible'` or `return False`,  if something like that is actually expected?

Comment: We are asked to output `none` if there is no way.

Comment: I changed the output to `none` for the False case as well before trying out the code in our compiler, still `IndexError` for hidden case 2 and 3.

Comment: @muw I've reread your question and stumbled over this requirement: "... one character at a time **such that every transformed string is still present in the list of strings**." Maybe that's the reason. Try the update last suggestion, which avoids manipulating the original list.

Comment: Tried the one without `deque`, still `IndexError` for case 2 and 3. There is actually an additional input. Before all the inputs,  there is a preliminary input `T` denoting the number of test cases. I omitted it in this problem because I initially think that it would not affect the result since I'll just loop it `T` times. I posted the entire code.

Comment: Update! It seems like the problem was with the compiler. After fixing the compiler, your code ran flawlessly!